# Connect telegram bot on PythonAnywhere by IP address

Tags: python, ip, telegram, pythonanywhere

I am making telegram bot on  pythonanywhere.com. I am trying to connect my bot to https://wallet.advcash.com/, but it needs my IP address. I have no idea which one IP address I should pass to advcash.

PythonAnywhere are load-launched across a cluster of machines. Telegram doesn't show its IP  How to know my IP and which one to use?

Comment: Check out [this PythonAnywhere help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/StaticIPForExternalWhitelists)